# How to make pyplot scatter markers opaque?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, alpha

I want to make a plot of lines with opaque scatter markers superimposed on them at certain points.  But the lines keep shining through markers, even with `alpha=1`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.close('all')
plt.plot([0, 2], [0, 0], color='black')
plt.scatter([1], [0], color='red', alpha=1)
plt.savefig('/tmp/foo.png')
```

[image: red marker not opaque at all]

How to make the red marker really opaque, i.e. make the black line completely invisible beneath it?

Comment: @JohanC Yes, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the z-order of the elements. Default, lines will be drawn on top of markers. Use `plt.scatter(..., zorder=3)` to force the markers on top.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([0, 2], [0, 0], color='black')
plt.scatter([1], [0], color='red', alpha=1, zorder=3)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]